# How to add new line on persist()

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello im currently working on a customization i want to ask if it is possible to add a new line here on persist()

[image]

i want to add WTAX from my inventoryID selector
[image]

thank you for helping i do not know how to start coding this certain customization

```
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    { 
          //I dont know what code to put here code to add new row
      baseMethod();
    }
```

Comment: you need to show some of your [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) or at least some [search attempts](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**found the solution :**

```
 PXCache cache = Base.Transactions.Cache;

 APTran line = new APTran();

 cache.Insert(line);
```